# InverseFunction oddity

Tags: inverse

```
InverseFunction[ConditionalExpression[#, 0 <= # <= 1] &]
InverseFunction[ConditionalExpression[#, -1 <= # <= 1] &]
```

The first line produces what I would expect:

```
ConditionalExpression[#1, 0 <= #1 <= 1] &
```

But when I make the lower limit in `ConditionalExpression` negative, the inequalities become strict:

```
ConditionalExpression[#1, -1 < #1 < 1] &
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: This bug has been handled at least in mma10.1.:)

Answer (score 2):

In the second case, the `InverseFunction` is computed by `Solve`, similarly to

```
In[1]:= Solve[x == y && -1 <= x <= 1 && Element[y, Reals], x]

Out[1]= {{x -> ConditionalExpression[y, -1 < y < 1]}}
```

According to the documentation,

> `Solve` gives generic solutions only. Solutions that are valid only when continuous parameters satisfy equations are removed. Additional solutions can be obtained by using nondefault settings for `MaxExtraConditions`.

For example, the following gives the desired answer.

```
In[2]:= SetOptions[Solve, MaxExtraConditions -> All];
        InverseFunction[ConditionalExpression[#, -1 <= # <= 1] &]

Out[3]= ConditionalExpression[#1, -1 <= #1 <= 1] &
```